# Laravel error 403 Forbidden (storage)

Tags: php, laravel, permisos, storage, error-403

¡Hola a todos! Soy novato en esto de Laravel (versión 8) y tengo problemas a la hora de visualizar el contenido que se encuentra dentro de `public/storage`.

Ejecuto Laravel en un servidor compartido, el cual tiene `public_html` y seguí las instrucciones del proveedor de hosting, he tenido que ejecutar el comando `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel miapp` dentro de la carpeta `public_html` y posteriormente como recomiendan desde siteground, para cambiar el *document root folder* usa **.htaccesss** en la carpeta `public_html` con lo siguiente:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain-name.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain-name.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !miapp/public/
RewriteRule (.*) /miapp/public$1 [L]
```

Realizando esto entra sin problemas a la carpeta de la app de Laravel y funciona todo menos el enlace simbólico de storage, el cual guarda en los archivos en `storage/app/public` pero en la carpeta **public** veo el enlace simbolico de storage y todas las subcarpetas con los archivos como se puede ver en la siguiente imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora bien, me he percatado que misteriosamente el enlace simbólico, el cual fue creado mediante la función:

```
Route::get('storage-link', function(){ Artisan::call('storage:link'); });
```

Tiene permisos 777 (no sé si es normal al tratarse de un enlace simbólico) pero si entro en ese enlace de `public/storage` las carpetas tienen permisos 755 y los archivos 644.

El problema al que me enfrento es que el server (sospecho) que bloquea la peticion y deniega el acceso porque me devuelve el siguiente mensaje de error cuando pincho en el enlace para abrir la imagen.

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access this resource.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Para ayudaros o poneros más en contexto, tengo un formulario en el cual permito el envió de documentos, y desde el controller le digo que guarde los archivos en una ruta dentro storage. Esta es mi funcion.

```php
public function guardar_documetos (Request $request){
   
   $user = auth()->user()->name;
   $year = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->year;
   $presupuesto = $request->file('input_attachment_factura');
   $name_presupuesto = $request->file('input_attachment_factura')->getClientOriginalName();
   $memoria = $request->file('input_attachment_memoria');
   $name_memoria = $request->file('input_attachment_memoria')->getClientOriginalName();

   $factura = new Factura;

   $factura->attach_presupuesto = $presupuesto->storeAs("public/presupuesto/$year/$user", $name_presupuesto);

   $factura->attach_memoria = $memoria->storeAs("public/memoria/$year/$user", $name_memoria);

   $factura->save();
```

*Perdonad si es un poco chapucera, y es un poco español/ingles raro, debo mejorar con el tema naming*

Con esta función guardo bien en **/storage** no hay ningún problema, ahora en la vista donde tengo los enlaces para abrir los documentos hago una llamada a `Storage::url` para sacar la ruta donde se encuentran, queda de la siguiente forma:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ Storage::url($factura->attach_presupuesto) }}">Ver presupuesto</a></li>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ Storage::url($factura->attach_memoria) }}">Ver memoria</a>
```

Archivo filesystems.php

```
'public' => [
 'driver' => 'local',
 'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
 'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
 'visibility' => 'public',
],

'links' => [
 public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
],
```

Esto me lleva al error 403 Forbidden, me he bajado el proyecto y ejecutado en localhost y funciona correctamente. ¿Hay alguna solución?

Gracias por la ayuda de antemano.

Comment: ¿Estás guardando los archivos en una carpeta fuera de `public_html`? Si la respuesta es afirmativa, no puedes acceder directamente a ellos. Para descargar vas a tener que leerlos en Laravel y enviarlos al navegador, puede ser con [readfile()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.readfile.php)

Comment: Si estas en linux a mi me ha sucedido antes y lo resulvo ejecutando 2 comando en la termial `sudo chmod -R 0777 your/path/storage`  y `sudo chown -R $USER:www-data your/path/storage` ya con esos ejecutado como root queda listo

Comment: El primero da permisos 0777 a tla carpeta storage y su contenido el segundo dice que tanto tu $USER como www-data(apache) son propietarios de la carpeta.

Comment: Prueba a poner en el storage permisos 775 o 777. Laravel no solo necesita el storage para guardar ficheros sino escribir en los logs, que se almacenan en este directorio.

Comment: Gracias a todos por las respuestas!, realicé `sudo chmod -R 0777 your/path/storage` y `sudo chown -R $USER:www-data your/path/storage` y al principio nada había cambiado no me mostraba nada, al tratarse de hosting compartido y no tener yo el control total decidí darle unas horas, ya que a veces tardan en efectuar los cambios, y hoy ya me ha funcionado todo correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

El problema está al momento de ejecutar el comando:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

ya que lo estamos ejecutando como root y al intentar acceder al recurso nos devolverá un error 403 (prohibido).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tendremos pues que cambiar el grupo:propietario dentro de la carpeta "public" donde está ubicado el enlace simbólico:

```
chown -h user storage
```

De esta manera quedará solucionado el problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]